# I need fields of table between specific dates in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table 'PORT_DTLS' with following fields: TN, Status_id, Req_Start_Time.  Req_Start_Time has the time in this below format '8/12/2017 2:22:14.490361 PM'.

I have tried with this query..

```
select TN,Status_id 
from PORT_DTLS 
where Req_Start_Time between '8/11/2017 2:22:14.490361 PM' 
                         and '8/12/2017 2:22:14.490361 PM';
```

But I am getting 'not a valid month' error.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Please post a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: The datatype of the `Req_Start_Time` isn't specified. OP says that the values have a "format", which indicates that very likely it's stored as VARCHAR, which of course is a SQL Anti-Pattern, storing "datetime" values in character columns, rather than the datatypes specifically designed to handle date time values. My favorite datetime is **`'06/06/2015 beer:30'`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like the column is a TIMESTAMP not a DATE.  You should use an explicit formatting to cast those strings appropriately.

```
select TN,Status_id 
from PORT_DTLS 
where Req_Start_Time between to_timestamp('8/11/2017 14:22:14.490361' , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
                   and to_timestamp('8/12/2017 14:22:14.490361','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

I've assumed your dates are `DD/MM`; perhaps they are really `MM/DD`, in which case you need to tweak the format masks I posted.  Most likely that ambiguity is why you're getting that `ORA-01843` error.

Comment: If `Req_Start_Time` is character type, that would need to be converted as well. (We can't tell what the datatype of that column, OP only said it had a "format", which makes us suspicious that it's character.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - I don't think `Req_Start_Time` is defined with a character datatype..  Comparing string literals with a VARCHAR2 column wouldn't throw `not a valid month`

Comment: i missed the error message. Usually, Oracle error messages start with **`ORA-`** (or**`TNS-`** or some other TLA), followed by a five digit number, and then followed by some message text.

Comment: The OP posted the message text but not the ORA number.

Comment: Like I said,  I missed it.